# Extending a $C^¹$ real function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $g: \mathbb{R}^{n}\backslash \{0\}(n\geq2) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$ function. Suppose that, for every i=1,2,...,n, $|\frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x_{j}}|\leq M$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}\backslash {0}$.

Show that g can be extended for a continuous function.

Comment: And what part of this is giving you trouble?

Comment: Sorry. I don't know how to start. I believe this question is equivalent to showing that  $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)$ exists. Because if this limit exists, then I can defined $g(0)=\lim_{x->0}g(x)$.

Comment: Please keep track, is it $f$ or $g$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $x,y \in \mathbb R^n\setminus \{0\}.$ If $x,y$ are linearly independent, then the standard mean value inequality gives

$$|f(y) - f(x)| \le \sup_{[x,y]} |\nabla f|\cdot |y-x| \le \sqrt n M |y-x|.$$

The same will hold if $x,y$ are linearly dependent, but you need a slightly different argument.